# Printer driver will not work under Linux

Tags: network-printer, kubuntu, cups

I am attempting to use a Ricoh Aficio MP 2000 printer on Kubuntu 13.04, to no avail. It sees the printer (and other printers) and can print successfully to other printers, including another Ricoh printer, but I get driver errors on the MP 2000 regardless of which one I use.

I have tried the Gutenprint one, the [Openprinting.org](https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Ricoh/Ricoh-Aficio_MP_2000) one, and the other two default options, as well as downloading a straight PPD. They all result in a paper size/type mismatch error. I can then choose to form feed, and they give me one of the following errors:

> `%!`
>   `userdict dup(/004) cvn{}put (\004\00`
>
> `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`
>   `%%%% If you can read this you are us`
>   `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`

There is more to the error, but that is all that prints.

> `%!PS-Adobe-3.0`
>                 `%% %%`
>                 `mark`
>   `()  ()  (2013091`

There is likely more to that error as well, but I could not find it.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Any information leading to the <del>arrest</del> solving of this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use the PXL drivers, rather that the PS ones.

Answer (score 1):

In [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.printing.cups.general/26255), the solution was to use 
the PPD for the Ricoh Aficio MP C2050 PXL, rather than the one for the MP 2000.

This driver can be [downloaded here](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Ricoh/Ricoh-Aficio_MP_C2050).